# aws cognito id token and access token are still valid after call to signOut method

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

On calling `signOut()` method, session tokens like id token and access token are just removed from the localstorage. We are using Auth class from aws-amplify:
https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html

```
Auth.signOut()
.then(() => {
})
.catch(err => { logger.debug(err); this.error(err); });
```

They are still valid for the lifecycle of the token (by default for 1 hour). How can we explicitly invalidate id token and access token so that any intruder can't get hold of these and make API calls. If anyone has idea on this please let me know.

thanks

Comment: You keep the access keyid in the local storage of the browser is that right? Not the jwt?

Comment: yes right. Not the jwt. But id token and access token is used to access resources like  aws appSync. Anyone can retrieve both these values and form an auth token.

Comment: Can we configure it not to store them in cookies by any chance ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html#amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-revoking-all-tokens-for-user

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415086/cannot-sign-out-the-user-from-aws-cognito

Comment: I am not sure how  not to store to local storsge when using amplify. But it seems the token can be invalidated after the user logs out.

Comment: so as per the docs if we use globalSignOut() it will invalidate the tokens used. Also how can we use Amplify.configure() to not store tokens in the cookies ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248790/discussion-between-ashy-ashcsi-and-spiff).